# Adding two javascript functions(depending on input)

Tags: html, css

I have put together a calculator what calculates a price, depending on user input. It works fine with one input, but now I have to scale it a little with a second user input. But here's the catch: the user might not want to put anything to the field, so it will be empty. And that's the thing that brakes my code. I could duplicate the calculator function and return the values and add those two together in a third function, but it will not work when there's an empty value.

Just for the sake of it, some trivial HTML code:

```
//When I only calculate with this user input, its easy
<input type="text" id="rocktext"><br>
// But how to consider this and do the same exact calculations like with the
//first one and add those two result together?
<input type="text" id="rocktext2"><br>
```

The code in the end should look like:

1. Take first user input, calculate the price(like in code below)
2. IF(!!) there is a second user input, calculate the price and add it to
   the first one

Am I being a moron to try it with JS or just a moron in the firstplace?

Hope to hear from You, guys!

J.

The initial JS code is as follows:

```
function priceCalc() {
    var inputs = document.getElementById("rocktext").value;
    var length = inputs.length;        
    var accept = 6;
    var initPrice = 8;

    if (inputs<=accept){


                // Since the code is much simpler right now i just put the result in HTML as follows:
                document.getElementById("rockpricetotal").innerHTML = initPrice + " dollars";

                //I can also return  the the value calculated here like so:
                //retVal = initPrice;
            }


            else {

                var intLength = parseInt(length, 10);
                var lengthGap = intLength - accept;
                var totals = lengthGap * 0.8 + initPrice;
                var prec = totals.toPrecision(3);

                // Since the code is much simpler right now i just put the result in HTML as follows:
                document.getElementById("rockpricetotal").innerHTML = prec + " dollars";

                // Here also the return clause can be possible with the calculation result like so:
                //retVal = prec;
            }

        // And the final return as an alternative to the innerHTML :
        // return retVal;
```

}

Comment: what if you used `<input type='number'>` for both `input`s and gave them a initial value of 0.00 (`value='0'`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it scalable, you can add a class to all the inputs which may be in the function (something like `calcInput`), so you iterate all of them and if the value isn't empty (and if it's a valid number), you put it in the calculation.

Or you can just verify if the second input is empty, if so, calls functionOne, if not, calls functionTwo:

```
function twoDifferentWays() {
  var valueOne = document.querySelector("#rocktext").value;
  var valueTwo = document.querySelector("#rocktext2").value;

  if (!!valueTwo && !isNaN(valueTwo)) {
    callsFunctionOne(valueOne, valueTwo);
  } else {
    callsFunctionTwo(valueOne, valueTwo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! You are too kind!